# UIWebImage+ AFNetworking images shifting in cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a collection view. In the cellForRow method I set an object in my collectionViewCell. The setter for that object takes the object's image url and downloads the image asynchroneously using AFNetworking. (the setter is in the custom cell subclass )

However when I download new images and i reloadData, I have to scroll down for the proper images to load... And sometimes the images change cells or duplicate (but I know the object in that cell doesn't change because the object title is the expected one.

What is happening?

Comment: Might need to see code to answer this. Are you operating on UI elements on a background thread? That could be your issue...

Comment: It may be that because the image is downloaded asynchronously, once it has been downloaded, the image view where it should be displayed now has to show another image (because you scrolled up/down and cells are being reused). So it looks like it's not cancelling the current image download when trying to show another image. But this is guessing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the image to swap out without reloading the cell (or scrolling down) you will need to call:

```
[self.imageView setImageWithURL:<#some url#> placeholderImage:<#placeholder image same size as imageview#>];
```

AFNetworking takes care of caching images so you can be safe to call the same setter every time cellForRow is called (to avoid image reuse on different cells)

NB: Its important the placeholder image is the same size as the imageView - your image will be swapped out.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be mainly because of the cell being reused bu the collectionview. Try setting the `image` property of your custom cell to `nil` right after `dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:`

Comment: ...not really. AFNetworking's `UIImageView` category caches the images themselves, and your `UIImageView` object is still around - you're just setting the image to nil, not the view.